# How can I auto-load a popup then auto dismiss it after 3 seconds on section load?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I am using the Android Studio template called "Navigation Drawer Activity". It comes with an ActionBar activity and 3 preloaded "sections" in the menu.

I am trying to create a "loading" popup when one of the sections is opened. To do this, I swipe the menu open and select section 2.

I can only figure out how to do this using a button and onClick action. I do not want the button, but I want it to auto run when the section is opened then dismissed 3 seconds later. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
// get button
                Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
                btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Connecting");
                        builder.setMessage("Please wait while we connect to your devices...");
                        builder.setCancelable(true);

                        final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

                        dlg.show();

                        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                        Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                if (dlg != null && dlg.isShowing()) dlg.dismiss();
                            }
                        };
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: When do you want open popup?

Comment: @Apurva When the section is open, or clicked.

Answer (score 0):

U=Try this code

```
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {    
       public void run() {
          sleep(3000);
          if (dlg != null && dlg.isShowing()) dlg.dismiss();
       }
    };
```

Comment: After adding this, `sleep` is giving an error `Cannot Resolve Method Sleep(int)`

Comment: This seems to be missing some info... I think it should be `Thread.Sleep(3000);` Also, that throws an interrupted Exception. This also doesn't reference any specific section?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the easiest method. Open and closed after 3000ms.

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Connecting");
    progress.setMessage("Please wait while we connect to devices...");
    progress.show();

    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
```